# How can I make my neural network emphasize that some data is more important than the rest?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, data-science

I looked around online but couldn't find anything, but I may well have missed a piece of literature on this.  I am running a basic neural net on a 289 component vector to produce a 285 component vector.  In my input, the last 4 pieces of data are critical to change the rest of the input into the resultant 285 for the output.  That is to say, the input is 285 + 4, such that the 4 morph the rest of the input into the output.

But when running a neural network on this, I am not sure how to reflect this.  Would I need to use convolution on the rest of the input? I want my system to emphasize the 4 data points that critically affect the other 285.  I am still new to all of this, so a few pointers would be great!

Again, if there is something already written on this, then that would be awesome too.

Comment: It seems to me that the 4 data points are manually selected features you deem important. The whole convolution layer stuff is just performing automated feature extraction, so you would want to feed your pre-selected features into your network after those layers, e.g. directly into the fully connected part of your net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have any reason doing this since the network will infer that on its own. The weights will be reduced or enhanced for each input according to their importance considering the output.

What you could do though, is to have a preliminary network that is going to have the 285 component as an input, and then a new network that is going to have the 4 critical components and the output of the preliminary network as an input.

```
[285 compo.]---[neural network]---+---[neural network]---[output 285 compo.]
                                  |
                       [4 compo.]-+
```

For instance, you could treat a picture with convolution networks and then add some meta information later in a fully connected network to process everything.

Comment: Hi, this is what I ended up doing! Made an auto encoder off of your suggestion and it's running as we speak! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The neural network should more or less learn this thing by itself. Especially with newer approaches like deep learning & friends, where the amount of hand-tuning is almost zero. However, this does assume that the function which you're trying to learn is learnable and that the system you use has enough power to learn it. That's a function of the complexity of the network involved (number of layers, nodes, types of activations etc.), the learning algorithms involved, as well as the data you supply.

It's really hard to tell without knowing more about the domain you're addressing? What sort of signals are we talking about (I assume they're signals since you speak of convolution)? What are the four inputs about? I assume they have a different modality than the other 285.

Perhaps this [doc](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ayhYe72_20OoJ%3aftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/importance.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) will help a little bit though.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can let the network try to learn this relationship. However, there are good reasons to try to rethink the way you're formulating the problem. Also, the difficulty a neural network will have learning this function is going to depend strongly on your specific problem (and the best way to figure it out is probably just to try it and find out).

Let me try to help by making an analogy to a simpler problem: let's take your 289-element vector and assume that 285 elements take values from -1 to 1 and the remaining four take values from -1000 to 1000. This maintains your original premise: that the four variables are somehow far more important in determining the output than the 285. (I understand that this loses the coupled relationship between the variables, but let's run with the example anyways.)

This is a simpler example for two reasons:

1. it's easier to see why it's harder to learn
2. there are a bag of well-understood tricks to solve it

Compared to a scenario where all 289 inputs have the same input range, a gradient descent algorithm will be slower to converge on the heterogeneous case. (Extra credit: try this!) Geoff Hinton has a rather famous set of slides which describes this effect fairly well: [Lecture 6](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf). I believe this is also part of a Coursera course now.

Hinton's slides also touch on two ways to attack this simpler version of the problem. The first is just to pre-process your inputs. If you scale down the inputs to have the same mean and variance, your gradient descent optimizer will converge more quickly. The other is to use a more powerful optimization method, specifically one with per-parameter adaptive learning rates, which handles this case as well as trickier scenarios. Andrej Karpathy's [fantastic notes](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#ada) from Stanford's CS231n class are a good intro.

But let's tie this back to *your* problem: that there are four "special" variables which transform the entire input. Given enough time and input, it's possible that a network can learn this function. But understand that if this transformation is complex and makes the optimization landscape rough, your network will likely have some trouble dealing with it.

If there's a way to transform your representation of the problem to avoid this link, I'd say try to pursue that. If not, then be prepared to resort to some bigger guns to solve the problem.

Without knowing the specifics of your problem, it's hard to give more concrete advice. Plus, ultimately, you're the one that will be solving it, so you're going to be the expert eventually!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was already normalizing the inputs to 0 mean and 1 std deviation, but hadn't considered not normalizing the 4 critical inputs to increase their weight. Instead I set them to be included into the neural net after the other 285 had been condensed down. Intuitively, it seems that this would also emphasize the 4 variables, since their information is now equal to the condensed other ones. But since I'm still new to this I'm not sure if that makes logical sense. It's running as we speak, so I'll have an update once it's done.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not suggesting you don't normalize those four inputs. I was just using it as an analogy. I think you'll need a more substantial transformation. (And the two-stage network you seem to have settled on may work in this respect.) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

## To emphasize on any vector elements in your input vector you will have to give less information of the unimportant vector to your neural network.

Try to encode the first less important 285 numbers into one number or any vector size you like, with a a multiplayer neural network then use that number with other 4 number as a input to a neural network.

Example:

v1=[1,2,3,..........285]

v2=[286,287,288,289]

v_out= Neural_network(input_vector=v1,neurons=[100,1]) # 100 hidden unit with one outpt.

v_final=Neural_network(input_vector=v_out,neurons=[100,1]) # 100 hidden unit with one outpt.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, thanks for the advice!